# invalid number of parameter Backup file

Tags: file, cmd, backup

i want to backup file from C:\ to D:\ but i have some problem about the name of folder .name of folder is "C:\test back" and "D:\new" 
this is my code

```
@echo off
cd\
xcopy C:\test back D:\new
```

a error is invalid number of parameter.
when i change name of folder test back to test_back it still ok

```
xcopy C:\test_back D:\new
```

Can you tell me why and how can i do to batch file xcopy if name of folder have space bar.
Thank you . i'm new to backup file.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the `space` issue, and should copy the files including folders.

```
@echo off
cd\
xcopy "C:\test back\*.*" "D:\new" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```